# SQL Query with partial data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL tables:

**fixtures Table:**

[image: fixtures Table]

**events Table**

[image: events Table]

I want to query the tables so that I count certain specific occurrences. For instance, how many times have the home side been 2-0 after 25 mins. In this case it would just be once (id 1).

I'm able to query one side of the fixture but can't join it with another. Another problem I'm having difficulties with is querying when a goal isn't present. eg, if I wanted to query who's 0-0 after 25 mins, I can't picture how I'd query the events table for the Burnley vs Southampton game that has no information?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring the basic data you need using a `join` and `case` expression:

```
select e.*,
       (case when e.name = f.home then 'home' else 'away' end) as side
from events e join
     fixtures f
     on f.id = e.id;
```

Then for your query, I'll use this as a subquery.  To get the fixtures meeting your condition:

```
select id
from (select e.*,
             (case when e.name = f.home then 'home' else 'away' end) as side
      from events e join
           fixtures f
           on f.id = e.id
     ) e
where time <= 25
group by id
having sum( side = 'home' and type = 'Goal' ) = 2 and
       sum( side = 'away' and type = 'Goal' ) = 0;
```

If you want a count of the matches, use an additional subquery.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Thank you so much for your help Gordon!